# When $A$ has won $m$ games, probability that $m+ n$ have been played

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

$A$ and $B$ play a set of games, in which $A$'s chance of winning a single game is $p$, and $B$'s chance $q$. How do I see that the chance that when $A$ has won $m$ games, $m + n$ have been played, is$$\binom{m + n}{n} p^{m+1}q^n?$$

**Edit:** It's assumed that any number of games is a priori as likely as any other number.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  That's the probability that $A$ wins exactly $n$ games out of $A,B$.  To go the other way, we need an a prior distribution on the number of games played.

Comment: Note:  there is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb N$, so it doesn't make sense to assume that any number of games is as likely as any other.

Comment: Did you, possibly, mean something like "$A,B$ keep playing games until $A$ has won exactly $n$.  Find the distribution on the number of games played."  That's not what you wrote, but that problem makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume lulu's interpretation. This is the probability of A winning $m-1$ of the first $m+n-1$ games, then winning the last game, which is $p^{m-1}q^n \binom{m+n-1}{m-1} \cdot p = \binom{m+n-1}{m-1} p^m q^n.$

The formula you gave is incorrect. For $m=1, n=0,$ we should have the probability $p$ of winning a single game, but you get $p^2.$ The only difference is that $m$ is shifted by 1, so it might be a typo.